# Python Regex re module running indefinitely

Tags: python, regex, infinite-loop

I am trying to replace every instance of `Um` with `#Um`. For example, "Um, i have an Umbrella" would be "#Um, i have an Umbrella" where I want `Umbrella` just as is because it's not just `Um`.

Below is my code.

```
while re.search(r'\bUm\b', trans):
            trans = re.sub(r'\bUm\b', r'#Um', trans)
```

And my code does not stop running. It loops indefinitely. Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do the replacement, the string still matches the regexp you're testing, because there's a word boundary between `#` and `U` in `#Um`. A word boundary is any place where there's a word character on one side and a non-word character on the other.

So after you do the first replacement the string is

```
#Um, i have an Umbrella
```

The next iteration changes it to

```
##Um, i have an Umbrella
```

and it keeps adding `#` over and over.

Since `re.sub()` replaces all matches in the string (unless you use the optional argument that limits it), there's no need to do the same replacement in a loop. Get rid of the `while` statement and just use the call to `re.sub()` once.

Answer (score 1):

It is running infinitely because `search` just returns the first match it finds. So it will always be the same string in this case (because '#' is not a word character). And a non-empty string evaluates to true. You should just do it like this since sub will change all matches anyways:

```
trans = "Um, i have an Umbrella"
trans = re.sub(r'\bUm\b', r'#Um', trans)
print(trans)
```

Output:

```
#Um, i have an Umbrella
```